# Reading CQL time type returns UnsupportedOperationException, "No Encoder found for java.sql.Time"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm attempting to read a Cassandra table into Spark with the datastax connector. My table has 2 columns using the `TIME` data type. I'm using `java.sql.Time` as the corresponding type in the dataset, but spark throws

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for java.sql.Time
- field (class: "java.sql.Time", name: "start")
- root class: "model.Trigger"
```

I've tried registering the `Time` class with Kryo, but no luck. I'm wondering if there's a different class I should be using to interface with Cassandra's `TIME` type, or if there could be a scoping issue, as I register the class with Kryo in the main method but retrieve the data from cassandra in another (by passing the session generated from the conf to the method).

Thanks!

**Update 4/12**

I wrote a custom mapper to parse Time, but spark throws the following

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported type: java.sql.Time
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$.forCollectionType(TypeConverter.scala:1025)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$.forType(TypeConverter.scala:1038)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$.forType(TypeConverter.scala:1057)
```

with the following mappers

```
object ColumnMappers {
  private object LongToTimeConverter extends TypeConverter[Time] {
    override def targetTypeTag: universe.TypeTag[Time] = typeTag[Time]

    override def convertPF: PartialFunction[Any, Time] = {
      case l: Long => Time.valueOf(LocalTime.ofNanoOfDay(l))
    }
  }

  TypeConverter.registerConverter(LongToTimeConverter)

  private object TimeToLongConverter extends TypeConverter[Long] {
    override def targetTypeTag: universe.TypeTag[Long] = typeTag[Long]

    override def convertPF: PartialFunction[Any, Long] = {
      case t: Time => t.toLocalTime.toNanoOfDay
    }
  }

  TypeConverter.registerConverter(TimeToLongConverter)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't with the Kryo, but with the type you're using - by default, Cassandra connector doesn't provide a mapper for `time` type (see in the [documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/6_advanced_mapper.md#using-custom-field-types)), so you may need to implement it yourself as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/6_advanced_mapper.md#using-custom-field-types).

P.S. You may try to use `Long` type because it's 64-bit number, but I haven't seen explicit mapping in the [source code](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/driver/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/types/TypeConverter.scala#L476).

Comment: I see, so I'd write them as `LongToTimeConverter` and `TimeToLongConverter`? And as far as scoping, do I need to reference the converters in any other place within my `main` function? Or is the `registerConverter` sufficient?

Comment: Register should be sufficient. Although I didn’t do it myself for a long time, so maybe things has changed

Comment: Got it, thanks! Although looking at the documentation, I'm not sure I understand how I'd replicate the following component `def convertPF = { case EMail(str) => str }`. It looks like some kind of destructuring (possibly related to `unapply`ing the class, and I'm not sure how I'd extend `java.sql.Time`'s functionality to support that. Implementing the methods in an implicit class still shows a compiler error when attempting to destructure in convertPF